# Should i use the latest GCC version ( in general, and specifically today )

Tags: c++, gcc

I was wondering if it is safe to use the latest GCC version, or do people usually go a few versions back (and if so how many). Are there trusted versions which can be assumed to be (relatively) bug free, or can i safely assume (for non life saving programs) that the latest GCC version is safe to use?

EDIT:

By safe - i mean mainly bug free, i.e. in terms of execution.

Comment: If you want C++11 support bleeding edge is where it's at still

Comment: Does *latest* mean *HEAD* or *latest release* (4.6.2 I think) ? Should we assume that by *safe* you mean safe execution in production ? or is it Standard compliance that we are talking about (eg. safe as the code is portable and won't have to be changed) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. +1 although I believe the OP talks about execution safety here ("life savint programs")

Comment: I edited to clarify what i mean in terms of safe. I know there is no clear answer, but i wanted to get a feel of what version non-newbie (as myself) C++ developers decide to use. By HEAD - what do you mean? Could you clarify?

Comment: @dan12345 The current tip of the development branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of specific requirements to the contrary, I tend to use whichever version of `gcc` is supplied by my (reasonably up-to-date) Linux distribution. This policy has worked pretty well for me so far.

Comment: Yep, well i got into my situation since i'm using a network linux with an old 2006 distribution, which doesn't support c++11 - in which case i was forced to explicitly decide which version i want to download. ( The systems administrator guys here apparently don't value updating linux versions or in general doing their work )

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use the latest version, because it implements the latest features, fix bugs, but unfortunately introduce new bugs. Introduces bugs are usually on some weird corner cases, so I would assume it is safe to always use the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Better C++ 11 support is on the latest gcc version. You might to compile it yourself though Note that gcc 4.7 is almost ready for release, so, you might want to give it a try. I have done it quite often, with almost all gcc versions starting from 4, for the improved  C++ standards compliance, and, quite often, gains in compilation time and improvements on the optimizer.

In general, it is a good idea to use the latest g++ compiler.

However, in a few occasions I have had problems with the libraries that I use. For example, the version 4.5 of g++ broke the version of boost::xpressive that I was using. Or better said, it revealed something broken in the library. Plus, the higher you go with g++, the more problems you will have trying to compile your code with other compilers, lagging on new features implementation.

My take on that is to yes, use the latest compiler version, and use the good things that the new standard has, because they make me more productive and a happier programmer. Then, if I have to port my code to another compiler, I just tweak the parts of the code that I need to, which at the end doesn't take that much time.

Comment: Again a newbie comment - but in what situations would i want to port my code? I mean i'm writing it, and i can take my favorite c++ compilers wherever i go, no? Or are you referring to situations when the code is distributed for users other than me? just wondering

Comment: Here are the cases where I have had to switch compiler for at least a part of the project: if I need to compile the project on Windows, well getting the latest gcc version on Windows is usually difficult (I actually don't know how to do it). Another case is when you need to use the gcc bundled with some SDK, like the Android's one or Google's NaCl. Yet another case is if you want to try, for example, Intel's c++ compiler, which they say is better for optimizing loops (at some time I could get code that ran 9 or 10% faster with Intel compiler, but that was a long time ago).

Answer (score 1):

On the normal host system, I would go with what is provided by the OS/distribution, and maybe install a few versions in parallel. On my macosx system gcc-4.2 (OSX standard), gcc-4.6.2, gcc-llvm (OSX standard) and gcc-HEAD installed. That way I can pretty easily try out things, update gcc-HEAD to have the bleeding edge, but continue to have working and supported versions for my day to day development.

In a commercial/work setting, I would recommend being very anal in writing down the version numbers used, and actually backup the whole compiler toolchain, so that you can come back to a working identical system later on if maintenance needs it. Nothing is more annoying than having a compiler change slightly in annoying ways (missing defines, etc...).

This is even more important for embedded development, so far that I actually save the compiler toolchain into git. A slight bump in version in gcc could mean either a horribly annoying compiler bug (those happen much more often on embedded platforms I have the impression), or a bump in size of for example 40 bytes, which could completely obliterate your project.